# Mongoose How to show multiple results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to display multiple results with one query? I looked through mongoose's documentation. Function '.findByID()' return one 1 document. I am using it here:

```
router.route ('/friends/:id').get((req,res) => {
   Friend.findById(req.params.id, (err,friend) => {
       if (err) console.log(err);
       else res.json(friend);
   });
});
```

Now i would like to display all results which have in my second column "UserMain" by specified value. Mongoose offers functions like 'updateMany()' or 'deleteMany()' but I can not see 'findMany()' anywhere. I tried to do it in the that way, by passing just second columns value but nothing has happend.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT #1:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyfak.jpg)

EDIT #2:

```
router.route ('/friends/:UserMain').get((req,res) => {
Friend.find({UserMain: req.params.UserMain}, function (err, friends) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        res.json(friends)
    }
  })
});
```

EDIT #3 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yJFu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
router.route ('/friends/:UserMain').get((req,res) => {
  Friend.find({UserMain: req.params.UserMain}, function (err, friends) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.json(friends)
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: I corrected my typo, but still after typing, for example, /friends/Chris my localhost only is loading and nothing is happening. Console is clear and I can not figure out what is wrong.

Comment: may I know what is your field name for that "Chris"? is it `user_main`? if not, then change the `user_main` inside your curly bracket to the correct field name

Comment: for example the field name for the username in your db is `username`, then do `Friend.find({ username: request.params.UserMain}, `

Comment: "Chris" is value in the "UserMain" column. It is shown in EDIT#1. I was trying before with that change and also now and nothing helps. I have change my EDIT#2 to the most recent version.

Comment: oh I didn't know there's a screenshot of the json array there. So the fieldname is "UserMain" but you put "user_main" there. That's why the mongoose can't find anything since the key that you are using is wrong

Comment: okay now that you have updated your EDIT #2, it should be working fine now

Comment: okay I just realized this, you use `req` and `res` in your `.get((req,res) => {` but you use `request` in your `.find({UserMain: request.params.UserMain}, `. change the `request` to `req` or if you want to use `request` then change the `req` to `request` in your `.get(()`

Comment: Still nothing. I cannot believe. I have edited my EDIT #2.

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: Yes, almost everytime with any correction. I am receives a message: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Chris" at path "_id" for model "Friend".

Comment: Nothing has changed. I created EDIT #3 with console log from localhost.

Comment: hmm perhaps you haven't commented the `findById` with route `/friends/:id`, do you still have the route `/friends/:id` with your `findById` there? Because the error says value is `Chris` but path is `_id` instead of `UserMain` which I think the server reads `findById` first before your find by `UserMain`

Comment: OMG i love you <3 I have commented function above, but i had the second function with the same build. Thanks for your time. You saved my life.

Comment: pleasure is mine, I'm happy that I can help other people. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve many document within your database use `find` method which take as first parameter an object which represent clause with which to find documents that match that condition

```
Friend.find({ user_main: request.params.UserMain}, function (err, friends) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        res.json(friend)
    }
})
```

Comment: Still cannot manage with that. I edited my post. I want to be able to route to localhost address which look like in Edit#1 and see only selected data, selected by x in friends/x. Created function now looks like in Edit#2.